# "На латыни" или "по-латыни"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Считал, что правильно только первое, но *"по-латыни"* уж слишком часто встречается. Так тоже правильно? Действительно ли в большинстве контекстов разницы нет, как сказать, если оба варианта годятся?

Приходит в голову такой случай без взаимозаменяемости: *Он знает немного по-латыни* (нельзя сказать *на латыни).* Это единственный вариант, который мне кажется нормальным.

А можно ли сказать, например: *Это "морская" **по-латыни*** (о значении имени Марина)? Всегда считал, что надо говорить именно *"на латыни"* в таких случаях.

Answer (score 2):

Я не видел никаких источников, в которых бы рекомендовали "на латыни". Наоборот же, **по-латыни** фиксируется ещё в правилах 1956 г. (а может, и ранее, не проверял).

Приведу для примера [ответ Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=245655).

> Как правильно: по-латински, по-латыни (или, может быть "на латыни") во
>   фразе: "по-латински (на латыни) это означает..."?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Правильно: по-латыни это означает...

Кстати, лучше также **по-русски**, а не **на русском**; ну или же **на русском языке**.

Comment: Да, "по-русски" я безусловно предпочитаю "на русском". Но при этом почему-то считал, что "на латыни" — это совсем другой случай.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А мне привычнее "на русском", поэтому нужно себя постоянно контролировать. Так что я и с латынью не удивляюсь :)

Comment: ***Понятно))***

Comment: Интересно, что у Пушкина в "Евгении Онегине" **по-латыне** (в оригинале на конце "ять", если правильно помню).  "Латынь из моды вышла ныне: \\  Так, если правду вам сказать, \\  Он знал довольно по-латыне,  \\  Чтоб эпиграфы разбирать"...

Comment: Спасибо, tum, любопытно.

Answer (score 2):

Убежден, что оба варианта приемлемы. Совершенно точно, что оба варианта используются:

> Старушка со слезами поцаловала бледное томное лицо племянницы и села подле неё. В след за нею немец-лекарь, в чёрном кафтане и в учёном парике, вошёл, пощупал у Наташи пульс и объявил **по-латыни**...
>   [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)] по НКРЯ

или

> ФРАЗЫ **НА ЛАТЫНИ** ДЛЯ ТАТУИРОВКИ
>   https://uniquetattoo.ru/frazyi-na-latyini-dlya-tatuirovki

Также см. [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B8).

Ваш вариант *Он знает немного по-латыни* звучит для меня так же, как и *Он знает немного [слов] на латыни* (другое дело, что оба предложения сейчас, кажется, маловероятны).

Comment: *Спасибо, Aer!*

Answer (score 2):

Думается, что выбор конструкции «на …» / «по …» зависит от контекста.
В тех случаях, когда в предложении есть или подразумевается слово «язык», конструкция «по…» бывает просто неуместна. Например:

*В его библиотеке все книги по юриспруденции были либо на латыни, либо на русском.*

*На каком языке предпочитаете вести беседу? – На испанском.*

*В этой школе обучение всегда велось на <…> языке.*

*Пусть идет путями узкими

и просторами она,

на татарском ли, / на русском ли ―

песня все-таки одна.*

[Б. П. Корнилов. Разговор с татарским поэтом (1934)]